# How can I collect multiple values into an array and later use the array with IN clause

Tags: arrays, oracle, stored-procedures, in-clause

I need to do this inside a stored procedure in Oracle 10g/11g:

```
SELECT COLUM1 INTO SOME_ARRAY FROM TAB1 WHERE COLUMN2=P_COL2;
```

And then I want to be able to use that SOME_ARRAY in another query with IN clause, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TAB2 WHERE TAB2.COLUMN1 IN SOME_ARRAY
```

Is this possible without needing to create a TYPE? Maybe a dynamic array? A little code will be appreciated.

Comment: `TYPE` is the Dynamic Array you look for.! or simply a sub-query?

Comment: By sub-query you mean `SELECT * FROM TAB2 WHERE TAB2.COLUMN1 IN (SELECT COLUM1 FROM TAB1 WHERE COLUMN2=P_COL2)`? If so, I don't like that. Then could you please tell me how I would go the `TYPE` way?

Comment: Probably not possible, you would run into a PLS-00642 error, see http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_pls_00642_local_collection_types_not_allowed_in_sql_statement.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's create a Type as an Oracle Object to be reference from both `PL/SQL` and `SQL`

```
CREATE TYPE SOME_ARRAY_REC AS OBJECT
(
   COLUM1 VARCHAR2(100)
);
/
```

Now, DB object as `nested table` of the type we created above

```
CREATE TYPE SOME_ARRAY_TAB AS TABLE OF SOME_ARRAY_REC;
/
```

The PL/SQL

```
DECLARE
      PL_ARRAY_REC TAB1%ROWTYPE;
      TYPE PL_ARRAY_TAB IS TABLE OF PL_ARRAY_REC  
                INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;

      v_PL_ARRAY PL_ARRAY_TAB;

      v_ARRAY SOME_ARRAY_TAB := SOME_ARRAY_TAB();
BEGIN
      /* Bulk collect the records into local PL/SQL type */
      SELECT COLUM1 
      BULK COLLECT INTO v_PL_ARRAY
      FROM TAB1 WHERE COLUMN2=P_COL2;

      /* To use it in SQL we have to use a SQL compatible Type*/
      /* So copy the contents from local type to SQL compatible type */
      FOR I IN 1..v_PL_ARRAY.COUNT
      LOOP
           v_ARRAY.EXTEND;
           v_ARRAY(I) := SOME_ARRAY_REC(v_PL_ARRAY(I).COLUM1);
      END LOOP;

      /* Use TABLE() to cast the SQL compatible Nested table as normal table */
      SELECT * BULK COLLECT INTO SOME_VARRAY 
      FROM TAB2
      WHERE COLUMN1 IN (SELECT COLUM1 FROM TABLE(v_ARRAY));

END;
/
```

*PS:* I would rather prefer the SubQuery

Comment: I know, I would too, but it takes eternity to complete when I use subquery.